# android get actual image coordinates from an extended imageview after zoom and pan

Tags: java, android, imageview, zooming, coordinates

I'm trying to retrieve the real coordinates of an image, after the user has drawn a rectangle on a canvas over the image. For this I've used a LayerDrawable, with the bitmap image as the bottom layer. Unfortunately my solution works only, when the scale factor is 1 (no scaling has been performed). If the user zoomed and panned around a little bit with the current solution I get close to the coordinates, but something is amiss and they aren't accurate. Because I can't post the whole code here I've uploaded it to pastebin ([link](http://pastebin.com/GgpDxsjS)). I also do a little bit of preprocessing and scale the image exactly so it fits the available size of my extended ImageView. For that i use a ViewTreeObserver and on the predraw method I find out exactly how much space i have available and scale the image to that size, so it fits the bigger dimension and the aspect ratio is kept. The code for it is here ([link](http://pastebin.com/VWcXWTK9)).

The most important parts for this are:

```
private void fixCoordinates(){
    //get utmost left,right,top,bottom corners from both begin and end coordinate
    float left = Math.min(beginCoordinate.x, endCoordinate.x);
    float top = Math.min(beginCoordinate.y, endCoordinate.y);
    float right = Math.max(beginCoordinate.x, endCoordinate.x);
    float bottom = Math.max(beginCoordinate.y, endCoordinate.y);
    //reassign them to proper begin and end
    PointF b = new PointF(left,top);
    PointF e = new PointF(right,bottom);

    //m[5] and m[2] denote offsets (empty spaces) when they are positive
    if(m[2] > 0){

        b.x = b.x - m[2];
        e.x = e.x - m[2];
    }
    if(m[5] > 0){

        b.y = b.y - m[5];
        e.y = e.y - m[5];
    }

    //safety
    if(b.x < 0){
        b.x = 0;
    }
    if(b.y < 0){
        b.y = 0;
    }
    if(e.x > layers[0].getIntrinsicWidth()){
        e.x = layers[0].getIntrinsicWidth();
    }
    if(e.y > layers[0].getIntrinsicHeight()){
        e.y = layers[0].getIntrinsicHeight();
    }
    //we only have one scale factor, because in the preprocessing we rescale and fit the image
    setBeginCoordinate(b);
    setEndCoordinate(e);
}
```

after the MotionEvent I use this function to set begin coordinates to be utmost top and left and end coordinates to be bottom and right.

the actual mapping to the original image is done here:

```
private PointF mapBeginCoordinates(PointF beginCoordinate, PointF endCoordinate){
    float left = Math.min(beginCoordinate.x, endCoordinate.x);
    float top = Math.min(beginCoordinate.y, endCoordinate.y);

    double wAr = UtilFunctions.getAspectRatio(getOriginalWidth(), layers[0].getIntrinsicWidth());
    double hAr = UtilFunctions.getAspectRatio(getOriginalHeight(), layers[0].getIntrinsicHeight());
    left = (float)((double)left/wAr);
    top = (float)((double)top/hAr);

    float[] imageMatrix = new float[9];
    getImageMatrix().getValues(imageMatrix);
    float scaleFactorX = imageMatrix[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    float scaleFactorY = imageMatrix[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

    float fixedTransX = 1;
    float fixedTransY = 1;


    //m[5] height m[2] width
    if(m[2] < 0){
        fixedTransX = (m[2]*scaleFactorX);
    }
    if(m[5] < 0){
        fixedTransY = (m[5]*scaleFactorY);
    }

    left = left/scaleFactorX + Math.abs(fixedTransX);
    top = top/scaleFactorY + Math.abs(fixedTransY);

    return new PointF(left,top);
}
```

the code is the same for the end coordinates. The code in pastebin is a bit messy, because I've been trying many different things for 2 days now to get it to work, yet something eludes me. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please precise result do you expect and  what you tried. Please have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use just a Matrix when drawing the stuff, doing that you can easily map any points you want by calling mapPoints()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by using the Mike Ortiz [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

the code I used to map the coordinates to the original bitmap is this:

```
private PointF mapBeginCoordinates(PointF beginCoordinate, PointF endCoordinate) {
    //TODO we only have one aspect ratio for the current picture, so we should remove redundancy
    float left = Math.min(beginCoordinate.x, endCoordinate.x);
    float top = Math.min(beginCoordinate.y, endCoordinate.y);
    double wAr = UtilFunctions.getAspectRatio(originalWidth, layers[0].getIntrinsicWidth());
    double hAr = UtilFunctions.getAspectRatio(originalHeight, layers[0].getIntrinsicHeight());
    if(!isZoomed()) {
        left = (float) (left / wAr);
        top = (float) (top / hAr);
    }
    if(isZoomed()) {
        PointF b = transformCoordTouchToBitmap(left,top,true);
        left = (float) (b.x / wAr);
        top = (float) (b.y / hAr);
    }
    return new PointF(left,top);
}
```

i still use the fixcoordinates code from above to prepare my left/top - right/bottom positions. Thanks for the answers